# Use function component ref inside a Parent class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-ref

Is it possible to access functions and vars of a function component `Child` from a class component `Parent` ?

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.child = React.createRef();
    }

    hello = () => {
        this.child.current.hello()
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                ...
                <Child ref={this.child} />
                <button onClick={this.hello}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

    hello() {
      alert("hello from Child");
    }

  }));

  return <h1>Hi</h1>;
});
```

Comment: This should work

Answer (score 1):

yes, your implementation should work.

You just have to change one small thing in your child

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const hello = () => {
    alert('hello from child')
  }

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    hello
  }))

  return <div>hi</div>
})
```